# Importing JSON file to MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, json, import, mysql-5.7

I'm unable to import .json file as a table in Mysql 5.7; All rows remain blank. I'm not sure where the error is.

I'm using the following json file stored under `/home/name/json_data/sample.json`

```
{
    "price": null,
    "sale_list": [
        {
            "buyer": "SmackMe089",
            "date": "April 29th 2019 21:20:50",
            "id": "1234",
            "item_desc": ""
        }
}
```

When I attempt to import it into mysql 5.7 using the following `sql` file nothing is imported.

file.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
         id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         json_data JSON NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/path/json_data/sample.json' INTO TABLE example_table (json_data);
```

Attempt to import into mysql:
`mysql --host=host_ip -u root -p db_name < /home/path/data/file.sql`

Comment: You can't use `LOAD DATA` in MySQL 5.7 to import JSON.  Starting with MySQL 8+ there is a new shell tool `util.importJson` which can directly parse a JSON file into a table schema.  If you have a persistent need for this, maybe consider upgrading.

Comment: I'm referencing https://mysqlserverteam.com/taking-the-new-mysql-5-7-json-features-for-a-test-drive/

I'm aware sql 8.0 has a nice shiny mysqlsh util to import json. I'm looking to work with what I have before migrating though and was referencing - https://mysqlserverteam.com/taking-the-new-mysql-5-7-json-features-for-a-test-drive/

Comment: Side note - @TimBiegeleisen - load data is supported so Im little confused what your rational is - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Yes, `LOAD DATA` is supported, but for CSV, not JSON, files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options are:

1. [13.2.6 LOAD DATA Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)
2. [7.2 JSON Import Utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-json.html)

Test:

```sql
$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.7.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.26    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`example_table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`example_table` (
    ->   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `json_data` JSON NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

**1. LOAD DATA**

**File**: `/path/to/file/sample.json`

```json
{"price": null, "sale_list": [{"buyer": "SmackMe089", "date": "April 29th 2019 21:20:50", "id": "1234", "item_desc": ""}]}
```

**MySQL Command-Line Client**

```sql
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file/sample.json'
    -> INTO TABLE `test`.`example_table` (`json_data`);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `id`, `json_data`
    -> FROM `test`.`example_table`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       id: 1
json_data: {"price": null, "sale_list": [{"id": "1234", "date": "April 29th 2019 21:20:50", "buyer": "SmackMe089", "item_desc": ""}]}
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**2. JSON Import Utility**

**File**: `/path/to/file/sample.json`

```json
{
    "price": null,
    "sale_list": [
        {
            "buyer": "SmackMe089",
            "date": "April 29th 2019 21:20:50",
            "id": "1234",
            "item_desc": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

**MySQL Shell**: As @TimBiegeleisen says, you can use [MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/) (even with MySQL 5.7), but you must activate [X Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com%20/doc/refman/5.7/en/x-plugin.html):

```sql
$ mysqlsh --sql
MySQL Shell 8.0.16

Your MySQL connection id is 2 (X protocol)
Server version: 5.7.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
No default schema selected; type \use <schema> to set one.

MySQL 127.0.0.1:15726+ SQL > SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.26    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.0004 sec)

MySQL 127.0.0.1:15726+ SQL > SELECT `id`, `json_data`
                          -> FROM `test`.`example_table`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       id: 1
json_data: {"price": null, "sale_list": [{"id": "1234", "date": "April 29th 2019 21:20:50", "buyer": "SmackMe089", "item_desc": ""}]}
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL 127.0.0.1:15726+ SQL > \js
Switching to JavaScript mode...

MySQL 127.0.0.1:15726+ JS > util.importJson('/path/to/file/sample.json', {schema: 'test', table: 'example_table', tableColumn: 'json_data'});
Importing from file "/path/to/file/sample.json" to table `test`.`example_table` in MySQL Server at 127.0.0.1:15726

.. 1.. 1
Processed 204 bytes in 1 document in 0.0007 sec (1.36K documents/s)
Total successfully imported documents 1 (1.36K documents/s)

MySQL 127.0.0.1:15726+ JS > \sql
Switching to SQL mode... Commands end with ;

MySQL 127.0.0.1:15726+ SQL > SELECT `id`, `json_data`
                          -> FROM `test`.`example_table`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       id: 1
json_data: {"price": null, "sale_list": [{"id": "1234", "date": "April 29th 2019 21:20:50", "buyer": "SmackMe089", "item_desc": ""}]}
1 row in set (0.0007 sec)
*************************** 2. row ***************************
       id: 2
json_data: {"price": null, "sale_list": [{"id": "1234", "date": "April 29th 2019 21:20:50", "buyer": "SmackMe089", "item_desc": ""}]}
2 rows in set (0.0006 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to use LOAD DATA INFILE to load JSON, because as the comments say above, that statement only loads CSV data.

If you want to load a JSON document as a scalar to insert into one row of a table, you can use the [LOAD_FILE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function.

```
INSERT INTO example_table SET json_data = LOAD_FILE('/home/path/json_data/sample.json');
```

This creates just one row to store the whole JSON document. It does not parse the JSON to insert separate rows for each entry in your sales_list array within the JSON.

Read the documentation I linked to for more information on the `LOAD_FILE()` function.

Comment: The MySQL shell (mysqlsh) has a parallel JSON/CSV/TSV bulk loader as of 8.0.17 (or so)